# Was able to cross compile Freetype2, now what?

Tags: android, android-ndk, freetype2

I was able to cross compile Freetype2 for android using this guide: https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20Freetype. How do now include it in my project? Do I need to redo it with a modified step, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wanted to post this in case someone else has the same problems as me.

I found this tutorial: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Android_NDK#FreeType
 and followed it. Then I copied the `freetype` folder created to my `jni` folder in my project. I then modified the `Android.mk` file in the freetype folder to be this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := freetype
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libfreetype.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/freetyp2 \
 $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/freetype2/freetype \
 $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/freetype2/freetype/config

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and my local `Android.mk` file to have this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := freetype/include/freetype2/ \
 freetype/include/freetype2/freetype \
 freetype/include/freetype2/freetype/config
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := freetype
```

Took a while, but it finally works!