# Running ./gradlew buildNative passes, but gradle build does not

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm currently working on a nbk project for android. I have the current commands in my build.gradle, so that I can build from my gradle wrapper:

```
def ndkDir = "/Development/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle"
task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
            'all',
            'NDK_DEBUG=1'
}

task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
            'clean'
}
```

I am able to build using `./gradlew buildNative`, but when I try `gradle assembleDebug` I get errors:

```
compiling TextRenderer.cpp failed.
/Users/user/android-ndk/san-angeles/app/src/main/jni/src/Renderers/TextRenderer.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found
#include <ft2build.h>
         ^
1 error generated.

compiling BoxRenderer.cpp successful.

compiling triangle.cpp successful.

Finished compileSanangelesArmeabi-v7aDebugSharedLibrarySanangelesMainCpp, see full log file:///Users/user/android-ndk/san-angeles/app/build/tmp/compileSanangelesArmeabi-v7aDebugSharedLibrarySanangelesMainCpp/output.txt.
```

I am using a freetype library that I cross compiled with issues, but I got it passed that point (I think): 
[Was able to cross compile Freetype2, now what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952632/was-able-to-cross-compile-freetype2-now-what)

Edit:

I have changed my gradle build to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        ...
        sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jni/freetype/lib'
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
        ...
    }
}
task buildNative (...){
    ...
}
task cleanNative (...){
    ...
}
```

But now I get this error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig$Impl
```

Comment: You should disable the C++ build that automatically launched by Android Studio gradle plugin when it finds CPP files in **jni** directory. Usually, to disable this task people set **jni.srcDirs=[]**, but I prefer to disable the C++ compilation tasks by name: `if (task.name.contains('compileDebugNdk') || task.name.contains('compileReleaseNdk')) task.enabled = false`.

Comment: Will this prevent the linking of the library to jni once it is assembled?

Comment: And where exactly did you put this in your code?

Comment: It's fine to switch to the *experimental* plugin, changing `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'`, but this involves preparing a new NDK build environment instead of **Android.mk**. It's probably not worth the hassle.

Comment: I don't understand your questions, unfortunately. Just don't waste your time on gradle configurations. Use the regular plugin, set `jniLibs.srcDir` and `jni.srcDir` in your build.gradle, and compile C++ manually.

Comment: I am using `com.android.model.application` currently. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: com.android.model.application is a part of your problem. You probably don't need the troubles of using an experimental gradle plugin. Just let Android Studio generate a new **build.gradle** for you, and add  `jniLibs.srcDir = lib` and `jni.srcDir = []`

Comment: Hey, so switching from com.android.model.application to com.android.application worked. If you want to post as an answer, I can set as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to struggle with the ever-changing C++ support of the [*experimental*](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) gradle plugin, you can simply use **build.gradle** generated by Android Studio. To disable automatic compilation of C++ files in the **jni** folder, you can override **jni.srcDirs**:

```
jni.srcDirs = []
jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jni/freetype/lib'
```

Here I override **jniLibs.srcDir** so that the library compiled with **ndk-build** will be included in the APK file.

Actually, I prefer to keep **jni.srcDirs** pointing at my C++ files (this way, I don't need another IDE running to work with them), and I disable the gradle tasks (somewhere in **build.gradle** file):

```
tasks.all {
    task -> if (task.name.contains('compileDebugNdk') ||
                task.name.contains('compileReleaseNdk'))
                   task.enabled = false
}
```

I can also teach the system to run buildNative and cleanNative when necessary:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
}

clean.dependsOn cleanNative
```

Note that the next version of Android Studio, 2.2 (now in public beta), [makes **ndk-build** a first class citizen](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/external-c-builds).

Comment: For anyone just reading this, I did not use the experimental plugin, just the normal `com.android.applcation` platform. Also, the `jni.srcDirs=...` follow the hierarchy: `android.sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs`.